# Xcode - Hardened Runtime is not enabled

Tags: xcode, macos, xcode10, macos-mojave

I'm trying to submit my app to Apple for notarized using Xcode 10 GM. But I'm getting this error -

> #### Hardened Runtime is not enabled.
>
> "AppBox.app" must be rebuilt with support for the Hardened Runtime. Enable the Hardened Runtime capability in the project editor, then test your app, rebuild your archive, and upload again.

[image]

I've tried to find this in the Workspace and Build Settings, but no success.

[image]

How can I enable Hardened Runtime for this Xcode project?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Ok, I found the answer. Hardened Runtime setting available in the **Build Settings** tab in **All** build setting section.

[image]

Also, If your application containing multiple targets then you need to enable Hardened Runtime for all targets.

Comment: Mine is enabled but still getting the same error. This is ridiculous.

Comment: This worked for me, but in an application containing sub-applications (e.g. an app set to auto-run at login set up as per Tim Schroeder's famous article, https://blog.timschroeder.net/2012/07/03/the-launch-at-login-sandbox-project/), I needed to set ALL applications in the workspace to have Hardened Runtime enabled. With only the main application enabled, the error would still occur.

Answer (score 8):

It is also available in Capabilities section

[image: Hardened Runtime in Capabilities section]

Answer (score 5):

1. Enable `Hardened Runtime` on the `Signing & Capabilities` screen to cover the app and frameworks.
2. Add `--deep` flag to `Signing - Other Code Signing Flags` on the `Build Settings` screen to cover the direct nested applications inside the frameworks.
3. Add a new run script phase on the `Build Phases` screen to cover the indirect nested applications inside the frameworks:

   ```
   codesign --force --options=runtime \
   --sign "${EXPANDED_CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY_NAME}" \
   "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${WRAPPER_NAME}/Contents/Frameworks/<PATH_TO_THE_APPLICATION>"
   ```